# Seperation of variables for Euler-Bernoulli equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the Euler-Bernoulli equation in homogenous case via seperation of variables. I've got to solve the equation

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial^{4}X}{\partial x^{4}}-\beta^{4}x=0$ where $\beta$ is the constant $\displaystyle \frac{w^{2}_{n}\mu}{EI}$.

I can see this has roots of $\beta,-\beta,i\beta,-i\beta$

and therefore will have the solution of $$C_{1}e^{\beta x}+C_{2}e^{-\beta x}+C_{3}e^{i\beta x}+C_{4}e^{-i\beta x}$$

From here I've tried to put it into trigonometric form but I can't seem to get the correct form which is: 
$$C_{1}[\cos(\beta x)+\cosh(\beta x)]+
C_{2}[\cos(\beta x)-\cosh(\beta x)]+
C_{3}[\sin(\beta x)+\sinh(\beta x)]+
C_{4}[\sin(\beta x)-\sinh(\beta x)]$$

Also is the process similar for a beam which has both ends fixed?

Answer (score 0):

$4$ integration constants require $4$ boundary conditions.  Some possibilities:

1. $X(a), X(b), X'(a), X'(b)$;
2. $X(a),X(b), X(c), X(d)$;
3. $X(0),X(\infty),X'(0),X'(\infty)$;
4. $X(0),X'(0),X''(0),X'''(0)$; etc.

Plugging in and solving $C_{i}$'s.

**P.S. :**
Writing the trigonometric form as $C_{1} \cos \beta x+C_{2} \sin \beta x+C_{3} \cosh \beta x+C_{3} \sinh \beta x$ is already good enough.